# has no exported member 'DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES'

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

i installed 'ng2-dropdown' in angular2 app. it gives

```
 error:  [ts]  Module "has no exported member 'DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES'. import DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES".
```

when i import  DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES in component as

```
import {DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES} from "ng2-dropdown";
```

i already did 'npm install ng2-dropdown '

Answer (score 0):

As per RC6 release `directives` are deprecated on `Component` metadata. You have to import `DropdownModule` module in your `AppModule` metadata declaration same as [simple example](https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-dropdown/blob/master/sample/sample1-simple-usage/main.ts)

Answer (score 0):

try to import using @ngModule like this

```
import {Component, NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        LIST_OF_IMPORTS_HERE...,
        DropdownModule,
        .....
    ],
    declarations: [
        MAIN_FILE_HERE
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        MAIN_FILE_HERE
    ]
})

export class ModuleApp { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(ModuleApp);
```

see changelog for RC6 here https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/4a740f2

you have to list down all the directives and pipes in the AppModule instead of component level as of latest release.